# Jquery .hover slider pause,

Tags: jquery, hover, slider, onmouseout

I'm trying to implement a on hover pause to a wordpress plugin called
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easing-slider/.

It seems to be using the following jquery slider to actually slide the images in a `<li><img src=""> </li>`:

```
/**
 * @version     $Id:  $Revision
 * @package     jquery
 * @subpackage  lofslidernews
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) JAN 2010 LandOfCoder.com <@emai:landofcoder@gmail.com>. All rights reserved.
 * @website     http://landofcoder.com
```

I've tried a few different options but can't get it to work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
jQuery("#lofslidecontent45").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);  
jQuery("#lofslidecontent45").hover(  
    function() {  
        jQuery("#lofslidecontent45").lof-main-wapper("rotate",0,true);  
    },  
    function() {  
        jQuery("#lofslidecontent45").lof-main-wapper("rotate",5000,true);  
    }  
)
```

And this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
jQuery('ul.lof-main-wapper').mouseover(function() {
jQuery(this).stop(true, true);
});
jQuery ('ul.lof-main-wapper').mouseout(function() {
if (jQuery(this).is(":visible") == true) {
    InOut(jQuery(this));
}
});
});
```

And this:

```
    jQuery(function(){
jQuery("#lofslidecontent45").slides({
hoverPause: true
});
});
```

Comment: You have an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: no i don't sorry give me a min and i'll see if i can put one up

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9HWcJ/

This is the actual site where it is hosted sorry i thought i had included it in the first question:
http://www.hairandmakeupbylavish.com/